# How to redirect all traffic to https except subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have recently redirect all traffic to https but I want to keep my subdomains on http only. Please help me to sort out this.

this is my rewriterules

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

this is my virtual host code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin  test@example.com
ServerName   staging.example.com
ServerAlias  staging.example.com
SetEnv       ENVIRONMENT staging
DocumentRoot /var/www/staging/
ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/example_staging_error.log
CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/example_staging_access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/staging>
AllowOverride All
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/example_dir_rules.conf
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin  test@example.com
ServerName   example.com
ServerAlias  example.com
SetEnv       ENVIRONMENT production
DocumentRoot /var/www/production/
ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/example_production_error.log
CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/example_production_access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/production>
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/example_dir_rules.conf
</Directory>



</VirtualHost>
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
#Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on

SSLHonorCipherOrder On

-------------ssl code----------

ServerName example.com

-------------ssl code----------

ServerAdmin  test@example.com
ServerName   example.com
ServerAlias  example.com
SetEnv       ENVIRONMENT production
DocumentRoot /var/www/production/
ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/example_ssl_error.log
CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/example_ssl_access.log combined


<Directory /var/www/production>
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/example_dir_rules.conf
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me to sort out this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "this is my rewriterules" - Where are your "rewriterules"? Since you appear to have access to your server config, then you should be performing this redirect in your virtual host - it will be more efficient and potentially easier to avoid your subdomains. Which subdomains? Or, rather, for which host do you want to redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: I have written rewrite rule in  /etc/apache2/sites-available/example_dir_rules.conf file and I have included this file to host file

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices.

**1.** Either you add a condition in your file to only match main domain

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Note that the rule to match `www` main domain can be removed since your main domain is `example.com` (no trace of `www` in your vhosts).

**Warning:** useless in some cases, you should not include the same file in all vhosts (see next point).

**2.** Or you can *directly* put a rule in `example.com` (http) vhost block. Indeed, others two (`example.com` for https and `stagging` subdomain) do not require rules to do what you want.

So, your config should look like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin  test@example.com
ServerName   staging.example.com
ServerAlias  staging.example.com
SetEnv       ENVIRONMENT staging
DocumentRoot /var/www/staging/
ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/example_staging_error.log
CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/example_staging_access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/staging>
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin  test@example.com
ServerName   example.com
ServerAlias  example.com
SetEnv       ENVIRONMENT production
DocumentRoot /var/www/production/
ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/example_production_error.log
CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/example_production_access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/production>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</Directory>



</VirtualHost>
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
#Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on

SSLHonorCipherOrder On

-------------ssl code----------

ServerName example.com

-------------ssl code----------

ServerAdmin  test@example.com
ServerName   example.com
ServerAlias  example.com
SetEnv       ENVIRONMENT production
DocumentRoot /var/www/production/
ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/example_ssl_error.log
CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/example_ssl_access.log combined


<Directory /var/www/production>
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: By placing the rules directly in the main domain's virtual host for HTTP (port 80) then there's no need to check `HTTPS`. In fact, in the code above, there's no need for mod_rewrite or a `<Directory>` wrapper. It's just a one-liner with mod_alias: `Redirect 301 / https://example.com/`.

Comment: @user82217 You're right, just forgot to remove the condition (even if it's always true and thus always evaluated). Indeed, we could totally get rid of mod_rewrite and use mod_alias with `Redirect` instead